# Why Success is an error for bash?

Tags: bash, cd

Working in bash I got an error:

```
user@host:~$ cd ..
bash: cd: write error: Success
```

It happend once, and next time I tried to cd everything went fine. But I do not want this error to repeat, so I have 2 questions about this error:

1. Why bash tried to write something while changing dir?
2. And more intriguing - why Success could be an error?

Comment: Something is very seriously wrong with your system. You may want to check for rootkits and other evidence of penetration.

Comment: Use Google! [Why did BASH print “bash: cd: write error: Success”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116381/why-did-bash-print-bash-cd-write-error-success)

Comment: @Thomas, that does seem to be exactly the same question, but it's of limited use because there is no definitive answer, only guesses.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's true, but if the OP mention it in it's question and tell us that it didn't helped the community may not consider it the same way

Comment: "Success is not an error; there's a bug changing the value of errno between the failure and the print statement". I object to the topic, inasmuch as it implies a falsehood -- that success is an error -- rather than stating a bug (that an error is reported as success).

Comment: (Also: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Indeed, if this *is* a bash_history bug, you **couldn't** get it when writing a script, making it only possible in interactive usage, which isn't topical here).

Comment: BTW, do you use rvm? (This rather popular tool puts `cd` inside a function wrapper, with quite a bit of complicated logic added).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why bash tried to write something while changing dir?

Bash keeps a history of every command you run, which ultimately gets recorded in `~/.bash_history`.  It's likely that the attempted write was related to that.

> 2. And more intriguing - why Success could be an error?

That's a display bug.  Success is not an error.

If you want the developer take on how it happens, I'm pretty confident in saying that:

- `bash` detected an error, probably via the return code of an I/O function, and
- it called the C `perror()` function to print an explanatory message.  By the time it did so, however,
- the C `errno` variable had been reset, if ever it had been set in the first place.

Usually such a reset of `errno` happens when you call another library function between calling the one that signaled the error and calling `perror()`.  Looking at the actual error message, it is plausible that the `bash` implementation called `sprintf()` to format part of the error message, but in doing so clobbered `errno`.